# How to solve delete using inner join in sql database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, sql-delete

I get the following error trying to delete records:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SPO"
>   LINE 1: DELETE SPO,SP
>                  ^

This is my code:

```
DELETE SPO,SP 
FROM stock_pack_operation SPO  
INNER JOIN stock_picking SP ON sp.id = spo.picking_id  
WHERE sp.company_id = 1;
```

Comment: remove "SPO,SP" from your statement. what should be the affected table?

Comment: you can't delete from two tables with one DELETE statement. to join another table you have to use `USING` see the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot join in the `FROM` of `DELETE`s in Postgres.

If you want to delete all the row from `stock_picking sp` with a `company_id` of `1` and all the corresponding rows from `stock_pack_operation`, you can use a cte with a `RETURNING` clause.

```
WITH cte
(
DELETE FROM stock_picking sp
       WHERE sp.company_id = 1
       RETURNING sp.id
)
DELETE FROM stock_pack_operation spo
       USING cte
       WHERE spo.picking_id = cte.id;
```

If want to delete all the rows from `stock_pack_operation` where the `picking_id` is one the `id`s from `stock_picking` for the company of ID `1` you can use `USING`.

```
DELETE FROM stock_pack_operation spo
       USING stock_picking sp
       WHERE spo.picking_id = sp.id
             AND sp.company_id = 1;
```